# How to search words (in a list) in pandas data frame' column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, arraylist

I have a list of words like this:
list1 = ["I","have","a","headache"]

and a pandas data frame like this:

[image]

I want to search word by word in the "list1" with the words in "keyWord" column and get the "id".

I would appreciate help and/or any pointers

I want to search the words in the list with the data frame. not to search the data frame with the list.

output must be like:

keyword    id

headache    1

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: `isin` with boolean indexing

```
df[df['keyWord'].isin(list1)]
    keyWord  id
0  headache   1
```

#### Option 2: `df.reindex`:

```
df.set_index('keyWord').reindex(list1).dropna()
           id
keyWord      
headache  1.0
```

Note that python and pandas are case sensitive, so `headache` is different from `Headache`.